# Java BigInteger , number theory , modular arithmetic

Tags: java, biginteger, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Anyone have an idea on how to implement such a problem in java ?

"Implement a subroutine that takes three positive integer arguments (a; b; n) and returns the
value of ( (a to the power of b) mod n), where the arguments are represented by about 100 decimal digits. Using four different methods."

Thanks in advance

UPD : Methods were be as following

M1)

```
public BigInteger Result1(BigInteger a , BigInteger b , BigInteger n){
    BigInteger Res = new BigInteger("1");
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0"); !i.equals(b); i = i.add(new BigInteger("1"))) {
        Res = Res.multiply(a).mod(n);
    }
    return Res;
}
```

M2)

```
public BigInteger Result2(BigInteger a , BigInteger b , BigInteger n){
    BigInteger Res = new BigInteger("1");
    for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0"); !i.equals(b); i = i.add(new BigInteger("1"))) {
        Res = Res.multiply(a);
    }
    return Res.mod(n);
}
```

M3)

```
ublic BigInteger Result3(BigInteger a , BigInteger b , BigInteger n){
    if(b.equals(new BigInteger("0"))){
        return new BigInteger("1");
    }
    else if(b.mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(new BigInteger("0"))){
        BigInteger Res = Result3(a,b.divide(new BigInteger("2")),n);
        return (Res.multiply(Res)).mod(n);
    }
    else{
        return ( (a.mod(n)).multiply(Result3(a, b.subtract(new BigInteger("1")), n)) ).mod(n);
    }
}
```

M4)

```
public BigInteger Result4(BigInteger a , BigInteger b , BigInteger n){
    BigInteger Res = new BigInteger("1");
    while(!b.equals(new BigInteger("0"))) {
        if(!(b.mod(new BigInteger("2"))).equals(new BigInteger("0"))) {
            Res = Res.multiply(a).mod(n);
        }
        a = a.multiply(a).mod(n);
        b = b.divide(new BigInteger("2"));
    }
    return Res;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @pbabcdefp concerning the (a to the power b) part , I have tried the following code snippet 

http://pastebin.com/McVawk6W

but unfortunately the project terminated without any outout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flustered this was put on hold...

For the sake of *theory*, if you wanted to write your own custom method please check the following out, based on a math trick to avoid the computation. First the solution, and then the math behind it.

Your subroutine could look something like the following:

```
public static BigInteger customPowMod(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger n){
    BigInteger previous = a.mod(n);
    BigInteger runningTotal = new BigInteger("1");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.bitLength(); i++){
        if(a.testBit(i)){
            runningTotal = runningTotal.multiply(previous);
        }
        previous = previous.multiply(previous).mod(n);
    }
    return runningTotal.mod(n);
}
```

The following is an example of how you could call the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005");
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger("6300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005");
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    //note the following produce the same values
    System.out.println(customPowMod(a,b,n)); 
    System.out.println(a.modPow(b,n));
}
```

**Now for the explanation**

I'm doing smaller numbers for the sake of explaining things... it's the process by hand that get's turned into the code at the end.

- let `a` = 17
- let `b` = 63
- let `n` = 5

**First** you want to see what base2 powers your power number `b` is composed of. For example:

> 63 = 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1.

OR in binary **11111**

This can be found programatically by iterating from 0 to our BigInteger b's  `.bitLength()` and and checking with `.testBit()` the given bits. *Hence the for-loop in the Java code.*

**Next** we find multiples of your base modulus (`n`) target (you need to go as far out in value as your highest power of two from the previous segment):

let us call each simplified value `a<power_of_2>`.

- a mod n = a1
- a^2 mod n = a2
- a^4 mod n = (a2)^2 mod n = a4 mod n
- a^8 mod n = (a4)^2 mod n = a8 mod n
- ...

and the by hand values:

- 17^**1** % 5 = **2**
- 17^**2** % 5 = 2^2 mod 5 = 4 mod 5 = **4**
- 17^**4** % 5 = 4^2 mod 5 = 16 mod 5 = **1**
- 17^**8** % 5 = 1^2 mod 5 = 1 mod 5 = **1**
- 17^**16** % 5 = 1^2 mod 5 = 1 mod 5 = **1**
- 17^**32** % 5 = 1^2 mod 5 = 1 mod 5 = **1**

Problematically this can be done in sync with the previous step of finding the base2 powers, each iteration you also find the newest `a<power_of_2>`. *Each additional square needs to be calculated until we've hit the max value, hence the ever increasing `previous` value in the loop.*

**Lastly**, we take our neccessary a values and multiple them by each other, followed by modulus of our `n`. *this is within the if statement of the foor-loop.*

- Again, we have the powers: **32** + **16** + **8** + **4** + **2** + **1**

and from the above step we have take the values and multiple them together (*followed by the modulus at the end of the loop*):

> **1** * **1** * **1** * **1** * **4** * **2** % 5 = 8 % 5 = 3

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly,
I think [BigInteger.modPow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) might be what you're looking for.

```
public BigInteger modPow(BigInteger exponent,
                     BigInteger m)
```

Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this^exponent mod m)

Alternatively (and more efficiently), you could also take (a mod n)  to the (b mod n) power, this should make the code run much quicker.

(a^b mod n) = ((a mod n)^(b mod n) mod n)

Comment: (a^b mod n) is not the same as ((a mod n)^(b mod n) mod n). If a=2, b=5, n=3, the first is 2 whereas the second is 1.

Comment: @pbabcdefp you can in general reduce the exponent modulo the order of the multiplicative group, which is totient(n), if you know it. But for public-key crypto, which is the only common realworld application of large integer modexp, the numbers are chosen so that a is already mod n and b is already mod totient(n).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You can only reduce it if the base modulo n is actually an element of the multiplicative group, which it may not be. For example, if n = 4, the order of the multiplicative group is 2. But if you work out 2 ^ 2 mod 4 you get 0. Reducing the power by 2 you get 2 ^ 0 = 1 mod 4. I know my number theory!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BigInteger` class for this if you aren't desperately needing performance. `BigInteger` is immutable.

```
public static BigInteger getValue(int a, int b, int n) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(b), BigInteger.valueOf(n));
}
```

Comment: Horribly inefficient-  the right answer is a CS/math trick about what's actually needed to be calculated.

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't see how this a "wrong answer." He didn't say anything about his other requirements.

Comment: @GabeSechan you've obviously not looked at the implementation of `BigInteger.modPow()`

Comment: @GabeSechan Considering he tagged the question with **BigInteger** it seemed as though that is what he was asking for. But maybe I read it wrong and should just go "quit this field permanently."

Comment: Well, for one thing your answer is just wrong anyway-  he said a b and n can have hundreds of digits and you're passing them in as integers.  THe other guy answered with modPow more correctly.

Comment: @gknicker, in Gabe's defense the original answer was something along the lines of `return BigInteger.valueOf(a).pow(b).mod(BigInteger.valueOf(n));`

Comment: @ArtyMcFly Thanks, I thought that's what I originally saw.